# Find values of $f'(2)$ for given expression

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = (x-2)(x-4)(x-6).........(x-2n)$ then $f'(2)$ equals

My work
$$f'(x)=(x-4)(x-6)...(x-2n) + (x-2)(x-6)...(x-2n) + (x-2)(x-4)...(x-2n)... (x-2)(x-4)(x-6)...(x-2n -2)$$
$$f'(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)...(x-2n)[\frac{1}{(x-2)}+\frac{1}{(x-4)} +\frac{1}{(x-6)} +...\frac{1}{(x-2n)}] $$
When I put two whole expression will be not defined but this is not the answer. 
Please tell me how to solve this

Comment: "When I put zero whole expression become zero" are you sure about this?  what happens to $\frac{1}{x-2}$?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write 2 and this will become not defined

Comment: You can't factor $(x-2)$ out of the entire expression and still get the answer. You *can* factor it out of *most* of the expression, as hinted at in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Write $f(x)=(x-2)g(x)$

Then $f'(x)=g(x)+g'(x)(x-2)$.

Comment: Why I am getting wrong answer with my method

Comment: @AakashKumar The two expressions that you’ve written down for $f'(x)$ in your question are not equivalent. The latter is undefined at the even positive integers $\le 2n$, which you yourself have noted for $x=2$, while the former is defined everywhere.